# pandas handle NaN/None inserts into sybase

Tags: python, pandas, sap-ase

is there already a working solution to insert NaN/None values from a pandas dataframe into sybase-ASE tables?

I tried the suggested solution after researching online (for pandas side):
df.where(pd.notnull(df), None)

However, when I try to insert this into sybase-ASE using bulk_copy/bcp, the None gets inserted as 'nan.0' for some reason.

Any ideas why this would happen or anyone knows of a workaround to accomplish these insertions of NaN/None as NULL into sybase? [sybase supports NULL]

---

full stacktrace for the DatabaseError:

```
df.to_sql('test_table', engine, if_exists='append', index=False, chunksize=1) 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/7ff6xgw24wvny74gfgzcvf6p88vc6k1a-pandas-0.15.2-16/lib/pandas/core/generic.py", line 966, in to_sql
    dtype=dtype)
  File "/7ff6xgw24wvny74gfgzcvf6p88vc6k1a-pandas-0.15.2-16/lib/pandas/io/sql.py", line 538, in to_sql
    chunksize=chunksize, dtype=dtype)
  File "/7ff6xgw24wvny74gfgzcvf6p88vc6k1a-pandas-0.15.2-16/lib/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1172, in to_sql
    table.insert(chunksize)
  File "/7ff6xgw24wvny74gfgzcvf6p88vc6k1a-pandas-0.15.2-16/lib/pandas/io/sql.py", line 717, in insert
    self._execute_insert(conn, keys, chunk_iter)
  File "/7ff6xgw24wvny74gfgzcvf6p88vc6k1a-pandas-0.15.2-16/lib/pandas/io/sql.py", line 692, in _execute_insert
    conn.execute(self.insert_statement(), data)
  File "/6rr1fqx3n9i93camwqhpfvylis5knyxh-python-sqlalchemy-0.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.7.9-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1449, in execute
    params)
  File "/6rr1fqx3n9i93camwqhpfvylis5knyxh-python-sqlalchemy-0.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.7.9-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1584, in _execute_clauseelement
    compiled_sql, distilled_params
  File "/6rr1fqx3n9i93camwqhpfvylis5knyxh-python-sqlalchemy-0.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.7.9-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1698, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "/6rr1fqx3n9i93camwqhpfvylis5knyxh-python-sqlalchemy-0.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.7.9-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1691, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "/6rr1fqx3n9i93camwqhpfvylis5knyxh-python-sqlalchemy-0.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.7.9-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 331, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
  File "/six2r9cj6gx8yhdpjygflakgnxyjxj2y-sybase-15.0-jump1.00-3/lib-python/Sybase.py", line 546, in execute
    self._start()
  File "/six2r9cj6gx8yhdpjygflakgnxyjxj2y-sybase-15.0-jump1.00-3/lib-python/Sybase.py", line 695, in _start
    return self._mainloop()
  File "/six2r9cj6gx8yhdpjygflakgnxyjxj2y-sybase-15.0-jump1.00-3/lib-python/Sybase.py", line 709, in _mainloop
    self._raise_error(e)
  File "/six2r9cj6gx8yhdpjygflakgnxyjxj2y-sybase-15.0-jump1.00-3/lib-python/Sybase.py", line 753, in _raise_error
    raise exc
sqlalchemy.exc.DatabaseError: (DatabaseError) Msg 102, Level 15, State 181, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near ','.
 'INSERT INTO test_table ("Token", "AssetToken", "InstrumentName", "Symbol", "Series", "Reserved1", "ExpiryDate", "StrikePrice", "OptionType", "Category", "CALevel", "ReservedIdentifier", "PermittedToTrade", "IssueRate", "SecurityStatusA", "EligibilityA", "ReservedA", "SecurityStatusB", "EligibilityB", "ReservedB", "SecurityStatusC", "EligibilityC", "ReservedC", "SecurityStatusD", "EligibilityD", "ReservedD", "IssueStartDate", "InterestPaymentDate", "IssueMaturityDate", "MarginPercentage", "MinimumLotQuantity", "BoardLotQuantity", "TickSize", "IssuedCapital", "FreezeQuantity", "WarningQuantity", "ListingDate", "ExpulsionDate", "ReadmissionDate", "RecordDate", "NoDeliveryStartDate", "NoDeliveryEndDate", "LowPriceRange", "HighPriceRange", "ExDate", "BookClosureStartDate", "BookClosureEndDate", "LocalLDBUpdateDateTime", "ExerciseStartDate", "ExerciseEndDate", "TickerSelection", "OldTokenNumber", "CreditRating", "Name", "EGMAGM", "InterestDivident", "RightsBonus", "MFAON", "Remarks", "ExStyle", "ExAllowed", "ExRejectionAllowed", "PlAllowed", "CheckSum", "IsCOrporateAdjusted", "SymbolForAsset", "InstrumentOfAsset", "BasePrice", "DeleteFlag") VALUES (@Token, @AssetToken, @InstrumentName, @Symbol, @Series, @Reserved1, @ExpiryDate, @StrikePrice, @OptionType, @Category, @CALevel, @ReservedIdentifier, @PermittedToTrade, @IssueRate, @SecurityStatusA, @EligibilityA, @ReservedA, @SecurityStatusB, @EligibilityB, @ReservedB, @SecurityStatusC, @EligibilityC, @ReservedC, @SecurityStatusD, @EligibilityD, @ReservedD, @IssueStartDate, @InterestPaymentDate, @IssueMaturityDate, @MarginPercentage, @MinimumLotQuantity, @BoardLotQuantity, @TickSize, @IssuedCapital, @FreezeQuantity, @WarningQuantity, @ListingDate, @ExpulsionDate, @ReadmissionDate, @RecordDate, @NoDeliveryStartDate, @NoDeliveryEndDate, @LowPriceRange, @HighPriceRange, @ExDate, @BookClosureStartDate, @BookClosureEndDate, @LocalLDBUpdateDateTime, @ExerciseStartDate, @ExerciseEndDate, @TickerSelection, @OldTokenNumber, @CreditRating, @Name, @EGMAGM, @InterestDivident, @RightsBonus, @MFAON, @Remarks, @ExStyle, @ExAllowed, @ExRejectionAllowed, @PlAllowed, @CheckSum, @IsCOrporateAdjusted, @SymbolForAsset, @InstrumentOfAsset, @BasePrice, @DeleteFlag)' {'@InterestPaymentDate': 0, '@WarningQuantity': 0.0, '@IssueRate': 0, '@ExStyle': 'E', '@IsCOrporateAdjusted': 'N', '@BookClosureStartDate': 0, '@BasePrice': 242030, '@ExerciseStartDate': 1127520000, '@OptionType': 'CE', '@BookClosureEndDate': 0, '@EGMAGM': 0, '@OldTokenNumber': 1, '@ExAllowed': 'N', '@IssueStartDate': 1120003200, '@ExRejectionAllowed': 'N', '@IssuedCapital': 999999999999.0, '@Token': 35000, '@ReadmissionDate': 0, '@LowPriceRange': 144550, '@DeleteFlag': 'N', '@Reserved1': None, '@Category': 1, '@ReservedD': None, '@ReservedB': None, '@ReservedC': None, '@ReservedA': None, '@TickSize': 5, '@NoDeliveryEndDate': 0, '@BoardLotQuantity': 25, '@Symbol': 'BANKNIFTY', '@Remarks': None, '@SymbolForAsset': None, '@Name': 'BANKNIFTY15SEP16800CE', '@FreezeQuantity': 2501.0, '@CheckSum': None, '@LocalLDBUpdateDateTime': 1121272656, '@MinimumLotQuantity': 25, '@PermittedToTrade': 0, '@ExpiryDate': 1127572200, '@NoDeliveryStartDate': 0, '@ExpulsionDate': 0, '@ListingDate': 1120003200, '@InstrumentName': 'OPTIDX', '@InstrumentOfAsset': None, '@ExDate': 0, '@IssueMaturityDate': 1127572200, '@ExerciseEndDate': 1127572200, '@CALevel': 0, '@InterestDivident': 0, '@RecordDate': 0, '@MarginPercentage': 0, '@EligibilityD': 0, '@EligibilityA': 1, '@EligibilityB': 0, '@EligibilityC': 0, '@Series': 'XX', '@AssetToken': 26009, '@MFAON': 0, '@SecurityStatusA': 1, '@SecurityStatusB': 2, '@SecurityStatusC': 2, '@SecurityStatusD': 3, '@HighPriceRange': 339510, '@StrikePrice': 1680000, '@CreditRating': None, '@RightsBonus': 0, '@ReservedIdentifier': 0, '@TickerSelection': 15, '@PlAllowed': 'N'}
```

Comment: As Sybase is supported by sqlalchemy (http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/sybase.html), this should just work out of the box with `to_sql` (no need to convert to Nones with `where`). What version of pandas are you using? And can you provide a small code sample that you use to insert the data?

Comment: Thank you for your response. My understanding (from a brief previous attempt) was that to_sql or pd.io.sql.write_frame does not work for sybase, but I will test this out again with to_sql. I am using 0.12.0 version of pandas.

Comment: Here is a code sample of how I convert the dataframe to a list and then do the bulk copy to insert this data into sybase ase:                          inList = df.values.tolist()                                                                                 blk = self.sybase_conn.blkcursor()                            blk.copy(table,direction='in')                                                   blk.rowxfermany(inList)

Comment: You will have to update your pandas version to at least 0.15 to be able to try if it works with sybase (in previous versions only mysql/sqlite were supported)

Comment: ok, thanks. I am trying to test this with pandas 0.15.2-16 now. The connection to sybase and sqlalchemy engine creation looks good.

Comment: However, I am running into the following error when trying to execute the to_sql:                                                                 dataframe.to_sql('sybase_table_name', engine, if_exists='append', index=False)                                                       sqlalchemy.exc.DatabaseError: (DatabaseError) Msg 102, Level 15, State 181, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near ','.
can't see anything obvious as to the root cause of the above DatabaseError.

Comment: Can you post the full error stacktrace in your question?

Comment: File "/six2r9cj6gx8yhdpjygflakgnxyjxj2y-sybase-15.0-jump1.00-3/lib-python/Sybase.py", line 753, in _raise_error
    raise exc
sqlalchemy.exc.DatabaseError: (DatabaseError) Msg 102, Level 15, State 181, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near ','.                                                                        Does this help? Unable to post the full trace due to size limitation here.

Comment: you can update the original question to include it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83225/discussion-between-prd999-and-joris).

Comment: This seems a bug in sqlalchemy. But, you have a rather old version of sqlalchemy (0.7.9, while the most recent is 1.0.x). Can you first try to update sqlalchemy

Comment: ok, tried with the latest version of sqlalchemy and encountered similar error:                                                                                                          In [9]: sqlalchemy.__version__
Out[9]: '1.0.6'                                                               dataframe.to_sql('sybase_table_name', engine, if_exists='append', index=False)                                                                                    
DatabaseError: (Sybase.DatabaseError) Msg 102, Level 15, State 181, Line 1

Comment: Can you try with only a couple of columns first? Do you then get the same error then? (or try only a couple of rows, some different things to see what triggers the error)